# Emacs - Strange Whitespace

Tags: emacs, console, whitespace

(I posted this same general question [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248517/emacs-strange-whitespace) thinking it had something to do with my emacs configuration, but after following a comment there, I think it is exclusive to `urxvt`)

My problem is that, under seemingly random circumstances, the point will be hidden by a large block of the same color as the point.  What is interesting about it is that it does behave as the point/console cursor does when I unfocus the terminal window, in that the normally fully-opaque box becomes hollow.  So, essentially, the point will suddenly appear wider than normal.

I use emacs in `urxvt` only, and I can currently replicate the behavior by pressing space around 5-6 times, at which point the point appears to be 2 wide.  This point-widening does not occur when I am in `tmux` or use `lxterminal`

Answer (score 3):

I found [a solution from an ArchLinux forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1018150#p1018150).

To easily fix, either add the switch `+ptab` when starting `urxvt` or add `urxvt*pastableTabs: false` to your .Xresources.